# Sequences covering all integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find research and maybe a field of study that would look at all the ways "to build the integers". I think that I am missing some key words. I know about covering systems,  primes, Fibonacci numbers or partition etc... but I am trying to understand the behaviour of a specific set of systems: the sets of output of recurring sequences.

For instance:

1. Starting with $n_0=0$ and formula $n_{i+1} = n_i+1$, one can see that $\{n_i\}$ will cover all positive integer.
2. Starting with $n_0=0$ and formula $n_{i+1} = 2*n_i$, one can see that $\{n_i\}$ will not cover all positive integer.
3. Staring with $n_0=0$ and formulas $$n_{i+1} = 2*n_i+1\\\\ n_{i+1} = 2*n_i$$ one can see that $\{n_i\}$ will cover all positive integer. We can picture that case as a tree with the root 0, then branches (1,2) by applying both formulas then branches (3,4,5,6) etc...

I am trying to find papers and research about when and how such recursive systems will cover all integers or not. I believe that I am missing some key words or that my problem is not expressed as it should be to find the relevant literature.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that your case 3 is simply the [binary number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) (modulo some small issues, e.g. you seem to be using $2n + 1$ and $2n + 2$).

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe "Beatty-sequence" and "Riordan-array" are good keywords. Maybe I'm far off road, I've only vague memory for that.